# setcookie not working on Remember Login Script

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, authentication, login-script

Hey im working on implementing a "Remember Login" but cant get the cookie to work in login function. Session cookies are all fine.
Somehow the setcookie function doesnt set the cookie. I have other scripts where it works fine but I cant figure out, why this doesnt work.... Am I missing something?

**Login.php**

```
sec_session_start();

if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
    //Success!
}
```

**Functions.php**

```
    function sec_session_start() {
      ini_set('session.save_path', '/tmp');
      $session_name = 'sec_session_id';
      $secure = false;
      $httponly = true;
      if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
          header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
          exit();
      }
      $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
      session_set_cookie_params(
        $cookieParams["lifetime"],
        $cookieParams["path"], 
        $cookieParams["domain"], 
        $secure,
        $httponly);
      session_name($session_name);
      session_start();
      session_regenerate_id();
    }
    function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
      if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
        SELECT 
        id, 
        email, 
        password, 
        salt 
        FROM users
        WHERE email = ?
        LIMIT 1
        ")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($userID, $email, $db_password, $salt);
        $stmt->fetch();

        $now = time();

        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {

            if (checkbrute($userID, $mysqli) == true) {

                return false;

            } else {
                if ($db_password == $password) {

                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                    $userID = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $userID);
                    $secretKey = hash('sha512', $user_browser . $userID . "158avcv");
                    $token = hash('sha512', $now . $user_browser); // generate a token, should be 128 - 256 bit
                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO users_sessions(token,userId) VALUES ('$token','$userID')");
                    $cookie = $userID . ':' . $token;
                    $mac = hash('sha512', $cookie . $secretKey);
                    $cookie .= ':' . $mac;
                    //////////////// THIS IS NOT WORKING //////////////
                    setcookie('hanterasRemember', $cookie);
                    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    $_SESSION['userID'] = $userID;
                    $email = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $email);
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                    $loginString = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = $loginString;
                    return true;
                } else {

                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```